# RestTemplate ignores @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, deserialization

`RestTemplate`'s `getForObject` method ignores the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on the class.

E.g. for

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Stock extends AbstractSObject
{
  // fields
}
```

and

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
Stock s = rest.getForObject("address", Stock.class);
```

I'm getting the following error

> Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "SomeField" (class
>   sandbox.Stock), not marked as ignorable

Answer (score 21):

Spring's `RestTemplate` expects `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties`.

If you are using the `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation from the older package for other purposes, you can manually setup the `RestTemplate` to ignore unknown properties:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

ObjectMapper lax = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter c = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
c.setObjectMapper(lax);

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(c);

rest.setMessageConverters(list);
```

Comment: This answer seems to say RestTemplate should work with fasterxml's JsonIgnoreProperties. However, I'm using that and getting the same issue (RestTemplate ignores it). For me, using ObjectMapper instead of RestTemplate resolves this, as ObjectMapper does recognizes the fasterxml JsonIgnoreProperties annotation. Interestingly, this answer provides the same guidance as the one above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443106/3368818. And I notice the OP there notes they're already using the fasterxml JsonIgnoreProperties.