# RestTemplate.exchange gives UnrecognizedPropertyException (ignores @JsonIgnoreProperties)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm using the @JsonIgnoreProperties to ignore the extra properties that my rest API is returning.

While this works for an ObjectMapper, it does not work from the exchange method on a RestTemplate.  I still get the UnrecognizedPropertyException when the server returns a property not found in the POJO.

Is there a way to support this for the exchange method?

Here's my code (I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyObject {

    private String id = "";

    public MyObject(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // .... getter and setter
}

...
ResponseEntity<MyObject> restResponse = 
                restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, request, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: how is the restTemplate object created?

Comment: It's just instantiated like this:RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()

Comment: which version of jackson are u using?

Comment: The version of jackson that I'm using is 2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties.`
You have to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties` with `RestTemplate`.

Or you can also configure your `restTemplate` with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to ignore unknown properties. Something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```

Comment: I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

Comment: You can also try to configure yourt `restTemplate`with a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. I've updated the answer.